# FutureCallback to Observable

Tags: java, callback, rx-java, observable

Is there a way to create Observable from FutureCallback ? I see that Observable.create is deprecated and is not the right way to do so (below).

I am converting

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<HttpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super HttpResponse> subscriber) {
            getClient().execute(httpRequest, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
                    subscriber.onNext(response);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
                @Override
                public void failed(Exception ex) {
                    subscriber.onError(ex);
                }
                @Override
                public void cancelled() {
                    subscriber.onError(new Exception());
                }
            });
        }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the other `create` [overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#create(rx.functions.Action1,%20rx.Emitter.BackpressureMode)):

```
Observable.<Event>create(emitter -> {
    Callback listener = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event e) {
            emitter.onNext(e);
            if (e.isLast()) {
                emitter.onCompleted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    };

    AutoCloseable c = api.someMethod(listener);

    emitter.setCancellation(c::close);

}, BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```

Comment: I am using rxjava-1.2.7 and this create method is annotated as Experimental which cannot be used in production environment.

Comment: Upgrade to 1.3.0.